# Unable to autowire in redhat fuse esb

Tags: redhat, apache-felix, apache-karaf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Hi I am using redhat fuse esb to build some services. The issue I am facing is while deploying it is unable to create object for the beans annotated with @Component, @Service.
I am using jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024 server and apache-camel-2.10.0.redhat-60024. Even I tried to change the redhat jar version in fuse karaf console, couldn't find a way to use latest version of redhat camel jar in my fuse server. Please help me out to do autowire in fuse server. I am using apache felix osgi plugin.

Comment: is @component/@service from spring / blueprint / cdi or something else?

Comment: does it workout outside Fuse ESB? eg are you sure all the spring configuration is correct?

Comment: yes, i have tested the same in fuse ide, there it works but when i deploy in fuse standalone server i dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache Aries BlueprintAnnotation project](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprintannotation.html).